# Пустые фрагменты после перезагрузки Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Я пишу Android приложение для Api 10-23, используя Appcompat. В `MainActivity` есть `ViewPager` на 3 вкладки-фрагмента. Код примерно такой:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
 private TabLayout tabLayout;
 private TabsFragmentAdapter tabsFragmentAdapter;

 private void initToolbar()
    {
     Toolbar toolbar=(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
     setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
     toolbar.setTitle("Looker");
     }
 private void initTabs()
    {
     ViewPager viewPager=(ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
     tabsFragmentAdapter= new TabsFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager() );
     viewPager.setAdapter(tabsFragmentAdapter);

     tabLayout= (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
     tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
     }

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

     DbHelper dbHelper= new DbHelper(this);
     dbHelper.initDb();
     DbHelper.initCursors();
     initToolbar();
     initTabs();
     }
 }

public class TabsFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
{
 private HashMap<Integer,MainListFragment> tabs;

 public TabsFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm)
    {
     super(fm);
     initTabsMap();
     }
 @Override
 public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)
    {
     return tabs.get(position).getTitle();
     }
 @Override
 public Fragment getItem(int position)
    {
     return tabs.get(position);
     }
 @Override
 public int getCount()
    {
     return tabs.size();
     }
 private void initTabsMap()
    {
     tabs = new HashMap<>();
     MainListFragment fragmentFilms= new Fragment_Films();
     MainListFragment fragmentSerial= new Fragment_Serial();
     MainListFragment fragmentMult= new Fragment_Serial();
     fragmentFilms.initFragment("Фильмы",O.interaction.CONTENT_FILMS, R.layout.main_list_element_film);
     fragmentSerial.initFragment("Сериалы",O.interaction.CONTENT_SERIAL, R.layout.main_list_element_serial);
     fragmentMult.initFragment("Мульт-сериалы",O.interaction.CONTENT_MULT, R.layout.main_list_element_serial);
     tabs.put(O.interaction.CONTENT_FILMS, fragmentFilms);
     tabs.put(O.interaction.CONTENT_SERIAL, fragmentSerial);
     tabs.put(O.interaction.CONTENT_MULT, fragmentMult);
     }
 }

public abstract class MainListFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterInterface
{
 private String title;
 public int contentType;
 protected int listElementLayout;

 public void initFragment(String _title,int _contentType,int _listElementLayout)
    {
     title=_title;
     contentType=_contentType;
     listElementLayout=_listElementLayout;
     }
 public void initAdapter()
    {
...
     }


 @Nullable
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
     super.onCreateView(inflater,container,savedInstanceState);
     View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_list_fragment,container, false);

     return view;
     }
 }
```

Много кода, вроде содержимого фрагментов, за кадром, конечно. Главное, что их инициализация происходит из базы, где `contentType` указывает на таблицу, на нужный курсор.

Собственно, проблема:

Когда происходит, например, поворот экрана, или, может, я ушел на пару-тройку активностей вперед, а потом сделал `taskKill`, `MainActivity` перезагружается и фрагменты заново создаются. После этого приложение падает от ошибок курсоров, которые смотрят не в те таблицы. 
Искал баг: поменял константы для `contentType` на 4,5,6 и выяснил, что при нормальном старте выполняется такая последовательность:

```
onCreate: main
initTabsMap: TabsFragmentAdapter
initFragment: 4
initFragment: 5
initFragment: 6
getItem: 4
getItem: 5
onCreateView: 4
initAdapter: 4
onCreateView: 5
initAdapter: 5
```

При перезагрузке:

```
onCreate: main
initTabsMap: TabsFragmentAdapter
initFragment: 4
initFragment: 5
initFragment: 6
onCreateView: 0
onCreateView: 0
initAdapter: 0
initAdapter: 0
```

В смысле, фрагменты создаются, инициализируются, но `getItem` не вызывается и кто-то (может Fragment Manager, я не знаю) выдает мне пустые фрагменты. Подскажите, почему так происходит и что с этим делать?

Comment: Не понятно зачем вы передаёте во фрагменты ID разметки через `initFragment`, а потом не используете. Также не ясно зачем вызывать `super.onCreateView`. Насколько я вас понял, проблема у вас в initAdapter, а его код вы не предоставили.

Comment: Я использую, в том же `initAdapter()`. Просто там код, которым инициализируются списки во фрагментах через `DbHelper` и курсоры. А еще там используются массивы полей и id для `CustomCursorAdapter` в каком-то из вариантов, представленных в наследниках. Я боялся, лишнего упомянуть, потому что тогда для полной картины придется дописывать еще кучу кода, будет сложно остановиться, а его и так достаточно. Именно лишнего. В данном случае достаточно того, что в этом `initAdapter()` используются `contentType`. Без них будут ошибки.

Comment: Сложно что-то сказать... Слишком много вопросов возникает. Возможно, вам надо попробовать возвращать прямо к-л фрагмент в из getItem и не пользоваться списокм оных. Ну или поменять супер-класс адаптеру ViewPager-а на какой-нибудь другой, типа FragmentStatePagerAdapter